# RotationTransition Stopped in wrong angle JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm creating animation that will start rotating from left top corner to center of scene then go to right top corner and stop the rotation. Everything works fine but when it goes to top right corner it stop in wrong angle.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;



public class ComeWaitGo extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
        RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), box);
        rotate.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        rotate.setByAngle(360);
        rotate.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        rotate.play();


        KeyValue one = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 125);
        KeyValue two = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 100);

        KeyValue three = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 125);
        KeyValue four = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 100);

        KeyValue five = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 250);
        KeyValue six = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 0);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> stopRotate = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                rotate.stop();
            }
        };

        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), one, two);
        KeyFrame frametwo = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(8000), three, four);
        KeyFrame framethree = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(11000), stopRotate, five, six);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(frame, frametwo, framethree);
        timeline.play();



        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll(box);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: here]

As you can see in image. when Rectangle goes to top right corner it not showing properly. ( Red line is just showing the path of rectangle (Image Editied))

So how I can get this animation? So the rectangle at the end should be in proper angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply animate the `rotate` property of `box` using the timeline too, instead of using a seperate `RotateTransition` animation in addition to the `Timeline` animation:

```
KeyFrame framethree = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(11000)
                                   /*, stopRotate*/,
                                  new KeyValue(box.rotateProperty(), 360d * 11000d / 2000d, Interpolator.LINEAR),
                                 five,
                                 six);
```

---

Alternatively combine both animations using a `ParallelTransition` to make sure both animations run synchronous:

```
// rotate.play();
...

Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

ParallelTransition transitions = new ParallelTransition(timeline, rotate);

EventHandler<ActionEvent> stopRotate = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        transitions.stop();
    }
};
KeyFrame framethree = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(11000), stopRotate, five, six);

timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(frame, frametwo, framethree);
// timeline.play();
transitions.play();
```

---

complete `start` methods as requested

Approach 1:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);

    KeyValue one = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 125);
    KeyValue two = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 100);

    KeyValue three = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 125);
    KeyValue four = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 100);

    KeyValue five = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 250);
    KeyValue six = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 0);

    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), one, two);
    KeyFrame frametwo = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(8000), three, four);
    KeyFrame framethree = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(11000), five, six, new KeyValue(box.rotateProperty(), 360d * 11000d / 2000d, Interpolator.LINEAR));
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(frame, frametwo, framethree);
    timeline.play();

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(box);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Approach 2:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), box);
    rotate.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    rotate.setByAngle(360);
    rotate.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    KeyValue one = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 125);
    KeyValue two = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 100);

    KeyValue three = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 125);
    KeyValue four = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 100);

    KeyValue five = new KeyValue(box.xProperty(), 250);
    KeyValue six = new KeyValue(box.yProperty(), 0);


    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(3000), one, two);
    KeyFrame frametwo = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(8000), three, four);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    ParallelTransition transitions = new ParallelTransition(timeline, rotate);

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> stopRotate = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            transitions.stop();
        }
    };
    KeyFrame framethree = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(11000), stopRotate, five, six);

    timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(frame, frametwo, framethree);
    transitions.play();

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(box);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: what does it mean? `360d * 11000d / 2000d`

Comment: @Nothing 11000 millis overall duration, rotation by 360° once every 2000 millis, so this is the formula to calculate the end value of the rotation (`5.5 * 360°`)

Comment: and your first approach didn't worked. It rotating even after reaching the top right corner.

Comment: @Nothing did you remove the `Rotate` animation? The first approach replaces the need of a seperate `RotateTransition`.

Comment: and your second approach also stops at wrong angle (more than my)

Comment: Yes I removed that already. Can you paste the complete working code after testing?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to reset the box's rotation in `stopRotate()`:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> stopRotate = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e){
        rotate.stop();
        box.setRotate(0);
    }
};
```